# Преобразование txt файла в xml, используя XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

Всем привет! Столкнулся с задачей, что необходимо конвертировать xml в txt и обратно, используя xslt. 
Написал код на xslt, который преобразует xml в txt. TXT со структурой [тег] _ поле.

Прилагаю код xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), ' ')"/>  
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        <!-- Инструкция xsl:if позволяет создавать простые условия типа "если-то".-->
        <xsl:if test="position()!= last()" >     
<xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>   
     </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

txt, для примера, выглядит так:

```
    country RUS  
    town Moscow  
    address 20, Zeleniy prospectus
и т.д.
```

Задача - написать xslt преобразователь txt-xml. До этого с этим не работал.

Comment: Обратная задача решения не имеет. XSLT работает только с XML документами. А XML документ содержит, как минимум, один корневой узел

Comment: А каким средством можно конвертировать txt в xml?

Comment: Например так `'<root><![CDATA[' + content + ']]></root>'`. Если кодировка не utf-8, то добавить еще и пролог